# Remap, rebuild json to custom structure

Tags: javascript, json

I found a ACID Akaline xls file converted it to json.

but it give me.

```
[{
  "Most_Alkaline": "Baking Soda",
  "More_Alkaline": "Spices/Cinnamon",
  "Low_Alkaline": "•Herbs (most): Arnica,",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "White Willow Bark",
  "Food_Category": "Spice/Herb",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Curry",
  "Low_Acid": "Vanilla",
  "More_Acid": "Nutmeg",
  "Most_Acid": "Pudding/Jam/Jelly"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "Valerian",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Bergamot, Echinacea",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Slippery Elm",
  "Food_Category": "1",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "Stevia",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "Licorice",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Chrysanthemum,",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Artemesia Annua",
  "Food_Category": "2",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "•Black Cohash",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Ephedra, Feverfew,",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "3",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "Agave",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Goldenseal,",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "4",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Lemongrass",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "5",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Aloe Vera",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "6",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Nettle",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "7",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Angelica",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "8",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Sea Salt",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Sulfite",
  "Food_Category": "Preservative",
  "Lowest_Acid": "MSG",
  "Low_Acid": "Benzoate",
  "More_Acid": "Aspartame",
  "Most_Acid": "Table Salt (NaCL)"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Mineral Water",
  "More_Alkaline": "•Kambucha",
  "Low_Alkaline": "•Green or Mu Tea",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Ginger Tea",
  "Food_Category": "Beverage",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Kona Coffee",
  "Low_Acid": "Alcohol",
  "More_Acid": "Coffee",
  "Most_Acid": "Beer, 'Soda'"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "9",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "Black Tea",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": "Yeast/Hops/Malt"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "Molasses",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Rice Syrup",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "•Sucanat",
  "Food_Category": "Sweetner",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Honey/MapleSyrup",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "Saccharin",
  "Most_Acid": "Sugar/Cocoa"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "Soy Sauce",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Apple Cider Vinegar",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "•Umeboshi Vinegar",
  "Food_Category": "Vinegar",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Rice Vinegar",
  "Low_Acid": "Balsamic Vinegar",
  "More_Acid": "Red Wine Vinegar",
  "Most_Acid": "White/Acetic Vinegar"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "•Umeboshi Plum",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "•Sake",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "•Algae, Blue Green",
  "Food_Category": "Therapeutic",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "Antihistamines",
  "More_Acid": "Psychotropics",
  "Most_Acid": "Antibiotics"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "•Ghee (Clarified",
  "Food_Category": "Processed Dairy",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Cream/Butter",
  "Low_Acid": "Cow Milk",
  "More_Acid": "•Casein, Milk",
  "Most_Acid": "Processed Cheese"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Butter)",
  "Food_Category": "10",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "Protein,Cottage",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "11",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "Cheese",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Human Breast Milk",
  "Food_Category": "Cow/Human",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Yogurt",
  "Low_Acid": "Aged Cheese",
  "More_Acid": "New Cheese",
  "Most_Acid": "Ice Cream"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "Soy",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "Soy Cheese",
  "More_Acid": "Soy Milk",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "Goat/Sheep",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Goat/Sheep Cheese",
  "Low_Acid": "Goat Milk",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "•Quail Egg",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "•Duck Egg",
  "Food_Category": "Egg",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Chicken Egg",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "Meat",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Gelatin/Organs",
  "Low_Acid": "Lamb/Mutton",
  "More_Acid": "Pork/Veal",
  "Most_Acid": "Beef"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "Game",
  "Lowest_Acid": "•Venison",
  "Low_Acid": "Boar/Elk/•Game Meat",
  "More_Acid": "Bear",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "Fish/Shell Fish",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Fish",
  "Low_Acid": "Mollusks",
  "More_Acid": "•Mussel/Squid",
  "Most_Acid": "Shell Fish (Processed)"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "12",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "Shell Fish (Whole)",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": "•Lobster"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "",
  "Food_Category": "Fowl",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Wild Duck",
  "Low_Acid": "Goose/Turkey",
  "More_Acid": "Chicken",
  "Most_Acid": "Pheasant"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Oat",
  "Food_Category": "13",
  "Lowest_Acid": "•Triticale",
  "Low_Acid": "Buckwheat",
  "More_Acid": "Maize",
  "Most_Acid": "Barley"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Grain Coffee'",
  "Food_Category": "Grain",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Millet",
  "Low_Acid": "Wheat",
  "More_Acid": "Barley Groat",
  "Most_Acid": "Processed Flour"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "•Quinoa",
  "Food_Category": "Cereal",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Kasha",
  "Low_Acid": "•Spelt/Teff/Kamut",
  "More_Acid": "Corn",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Wild Rice",
  "Food_Category": "Grass",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Brown Rice",
  "Low_Acid": "Farina/Semolina",
  "More_Acid": "Rye",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "•Amaranth",
  "Food_Category": "14",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "White Rice",
  "More_Acid": "Oat Bran",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Japonica Rice",
  "Food_Category": "15",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "Poppy Seed",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Primrose Oil",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Avocado Oil",
  "Food_Category": "Nut",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Pumpkin Seed Oil",
  "Low_Acid": "Almond Oil",
  "More_Acid": "Pistachio Seed",
  "Most_Acid": "•Cottonseed Oil/Meal"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Pumpkin Seed",
  "More_Alkaline": "Cashew",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Sesame Seed",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Seeds (most)",
  "Food_Category": "Seed/Sprout",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Grape Seed Oil",
  "Low_Acid": "Sesame Oil",
  "More_Acid": "Chestnut Oil",
  "Most_Acid": "Hazelnut"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "Chestnut",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Cod Liver Oil",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Coconut Oil",
  "Food_Category": "Oil",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Sunflower Oil",
  "Low_Acid": "Safflower Oil",
  "More_Acid": "Lard",
  "Most_Acid": "Walnut"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "Pepper",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Almond",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Olive/Macadamia Oil",
  "Food_Category": "",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Pine Nut",
  "Low_Acid": "Tapioca",
  "More_Acid": "Pecan",
  "Most_Acid": "Brazil Nut"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Hydrogenated Oil",
  "More_Alkaline": "",
  "Low_Alkaline": "•Sprout",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Linseed/Flax Oil",
  "Food_Category": "",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Canola Oil",
  "Low_Acid": "•Seitan or Tofu",
  "More_Acid": "Palm Kernel Oil",
  "Most_Acid": "Fried Food"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Lentil",
  "More_Alkaline": "Kohlrabi",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Potato/Bell Pepper",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Brussel Sprout",
  "Food_Category": "16",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Spinach",
  "Low_Acid": "Split Pea",
  "More_Acid": "Green Pea",
  "Most_Acid": "Soybean"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Brocoflower",
  "More_Alkaline": "Parsnip/Taro",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Mushroom/Fungi",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Beet",
  "Food_Category": "Bean",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Fava Bean",
  "Low_Acid": "Pinto Bean",
  "More_Acid": "Peanut",
  "Most_Acid": "Carob"
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "•Seaweed",
  "More_Alkaline": "Garlic",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Cauliflower",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Chive/Cilantro",
  "Food_Category": "Vegetable",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Kidney Bean",
  "Low_Acid": "White Bean",
  "More_Acid": "Snow Pea",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Noril|Kombu|Wakame|Hijiki",
  "More_Alkaline": "Asparagus",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Cabbage",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Celery/Scallion",
  "Food_Category": "17",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Black-eyed Pea",
  "Low_Acid": "Navy/Red Bean",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Onion/Miso",
  "More_Alkaline": "Kale/Parsley",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Rutabaga",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Okra/Cucumber",
  "Food_Category": "Legume",
  "Lowest_Acid": "String/Wax Bean",
  "Low_Acid": "Aduki Bean",
  "More_Acid": "Legumes (other)",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "•Daikon/Taro Root",
  "More_Alkaline": "Endive/Arugula",
  "Low_Alkaline": "•Salsify/Ginseng",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Turnip Greens",
  "Food_Category": "Pulse",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Zucchini",
  "Low_Acid": "Lima or Mung Bean",
  "More_Acid": "Carrot",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "•Sea Vegetables (other)",
  "More_Alkaline": "Mustard Greens",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Eggplant",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Squash",
  "Food_Category": "Root",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Chutney",
  "Low_Acid": "Chard",
  "More_Acid": "ChickPea/Garbanzo",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Dandelion Greens",
  "More_Alkaline": "Jerusalem Artichoke",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Pumpkin",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Artichoke",
  "Food_Category": "18",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Rhubarb",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "•Burdock/•Lotus Root",
  "More_Alkaline": "Ginger Root",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Collard Greens",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Lettuce",
  "Food_Category": "19",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Sweet Potato/Yam",
  "More_Alkaline": "Broccoli",
  "Low_Alkaline": "",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Jicama",
  "Food_Category": "20",
  "Lowest_Acid": "",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Lime",
  "More_Alkaline": "Grapefruit",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Lemon",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Orange",
  "Food_Category": "Citrus Fruit",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Coconut",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Nectarine",
  "More_Alkaline": "Canteloupe",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Pear",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Apricot",
  "Food_Category": "",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Guava",
  "Low_Acid": "Plum",
  "More_Acid": "Cranberry",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Persimmon",
  "More_Alkaline": "Honeydew",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Avocado",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Most_Acid",
  "Food_Category": "21",
  "Lowest_Acid": "•Pickled Fruit",
  "Low_Acid": "Prune",
  "More_Acid": "Pomegranate",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Raspberry",
  "More_Alkaline": "Citrus",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Apple",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Blueberry",
  "Food_Category": "22",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Dry Fruit",
  "Low_Acid": "Tomato",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Watermelon",
  "More_Alkaline": "Olive",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Blackberry",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Pineapple Juice",
  "Food_Category": "Fruit",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Fig",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Tangerine",
  "More_Alkaline": "•Dewberry",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Cherry",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Raisin, Currant",
  "Food_Category": "23",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Persimmon Juice",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "Pineapple",
  "More_Alkaline": "Loganberry",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Peach",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Grape",
  "Food_Category": "24",
  "Lowest_Acid": "•Cherimoya",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}, {
  "Most_Alkaline": "",
  "More_Alkaline": "Mango",
  "Low_Alkaline": "Papaya",
  "Lowest_Alkaline": "Strawberry",
  "Food_Category": "25",
  "Lowest_Acid": "Date",
  "Low_Acid": "",
  "More_Acid": "",
  "Most_Acid": ""
}]
```

I want to rebuid it completly with javascript to look like.

```
[{
  "aliment": "Baking Soda",
  "Food_Category": "Spice/Herb",
  "alcide": "Low Alkaline", // alcide mean acid or alkaline
  "score": "2",
  "color": "green"
}, {
  "aliment": "apple",
  "Food_Category": "fruits",
  "alcide": "Most Acid",
  "score": "-4",
  "color": "red"
}]
```

The rate could be build as follow.

```
Most Alkaline = 4
More Alkaline = 3
Low Alkaline = 2
Lowest Alkaline = 1
Lowest Acid = -1
Low Acid = -2
More Acid = -3
Most Acid = -4

red = Acid -1 -2 -3 -4
green = Alkaline 1 2 3 4
```

The [original xls](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JM0pJdvYqJcixTYzItBQzyQdd07KdmTVO3HO9MWIfDw/edit?usp=sharing) i saved online:

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. Can you make an example of the output if you just had the first two objects? What would come out?

Comment: The output example is there under "I want to rebuid it completly with javascript to look like."

Comment: What did you try? post code that you have tried. what is not working for you? Once you know how to read a JSON file with javascript you should be able to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I got what you want to do. And it can be achieved with a bit of code. But the JSON file is so messy, which is probably caused by poorly formatted excel table, that it needs a lot of working. For example the line below

```
"Lowest_Alkaline": "•Ghee (Clarified",
```

is not even finished. The rest is on the next element of array:

```
"Lowest_Alkaline": "Butter)",
```

Putting it all together is not an easy task. On the other hand, it is more easier if you try to change the source, the xls file. Than you can try to convert it into JSON format again.

Sorry i couldn't help, but i believe you should try the second option, which includes re-designing the excel file.

Good luck

> EDİT

I found time to do it, you can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B15OZA66s401d21pVThUcUwzSXc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I know someone could find a way with javascript

Comment: @gino, of course there is. I can do it. But i think i did not make myself clear. What i meant was the JSON file is vague and messy, as well as the excel file.

As for your desired output, there is another problem. In your Excel file, Apple is represented as "Low Alkaline - (2)", while in your desired output you wrote "Most Acid (-4)"

Or i might have misinterpreted at all.

Comment: I made it, just download it from above.

Comment: Great, how did you do that?

Comment: I did it by editing original Excel file. Did not take long. Glad to help

Comment: tank you for your patience, can you share this excel on Google doc?

Comment: I did some fix and a json to CSV conversion and load it on Google doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GIXd5G7Rfmg_Ny0x9UtQYftkmiFrUF520CaSJ4WPA8k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Good to hear that.